# How to get only the required table from excel sheet

Tags: c#

I am trying to retrieve data from an Excel sheet. I am getting the table data along with other extra data. So how to retrieve only the table from the Excel sheet.
Here is what i am getting:

I don't want the first 3 rows.

```
                    sdfdsfdsf   
                       dfg      hjk

Sl No   Name    Code    Date    Time    Door Name   Shift   Department  Grade
1   Channabasappa   535 01/Dec/08   9:37    WORK CENTER IN  General Shift   Payroll A
2   Channabasappa   535 01/Dec/08   13:42   WORK CENTER OUT General Shift   Payroll A
3   Channabasappa   535 01/Dec/08   15:40   WORK CENTER OUT General Shift   Payroll A
4   Channabasappa   535 01/Dec/08   16:09   WORK CENTER IN  General Shift   Payroll A
5   Channabasappa   535 01/Dec/08   17:42   WORK CENTER OUT General Shift   Payroll A
6   Channabasappa   535 01/Dec/08   17:43   WORK CENTER IN  General Shift   Payroll A
7
```

Answer (score 0):

We would need to see your code to pass comment.

But I think you'll find [this blog post](http://blog.lab49.com/archives/196) very useful, it explains a number of quirks to be aware of when reading Excel worksheets using ADO.NET.